# Passing dynamic webelement values to a Javascript method to perform a drag and drop in HTML5

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to perform a drag and drop operation in HTML5 using Selenium for Java. `Action` objects cannot be [used](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop) for this purpose.

I've tried this but now I'm stuck:

```
 @driver.execute_script(dnd_javascript+"$('#column-a').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#column-b'});")
```

Both elements taking part in the drag and drop are dynamic. I need to generate a dynamic XPath for both these elements based on their position.

How do I pass the values to the JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to put a placeholders into the javascript String and then supply the elements as varargs arguments to the executeScript of the JavascriptExecutor. For example:

```
WebDriver driver = ...;
WebElement dragged = ...;
WebElement dropArea = ...;
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$(arguments[0]).simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: arguments[1]});", dragged, dropArea);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Actions class for this purpose.

```
Actions objActions = new Actions(objWebDriver);
objActions.dragAndDrop(objWebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("expression1")), objWebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("expression2")));
```

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but the author of the question left a pretty big piece of information out of the question. The author left a comment on an answer that has now been deleted that Actions cannot be used to perform HTML5 drag and drop operations. The evidence is in that blog post linked to in the article. (The deleted answer was essentially the same answer as you are giving now.)